# How to align text in python

Tags: python

I want to align some text for a league table by using the sqlite3 module.

I want it to look like this:

```
    NAME            POINTS
    Arsenal         90
    Man United      85
    Man City        80
    Tottenham       70
```

but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

usually it starts with an effort but meh here ya go

```
print "  {name:<10} {points:<5}".format(name="Arsenal",points=90)
```